# About long layover at Istanbul

Tags: transit, hotels, istanbul

We have 13 hours layover at Istanbul while traveling to Europe by Turkish Airlines. We don’t have a transit visa. Can we book a room night at any hotel within the airport premises?

Answer (score 2):

There is the [YOTEL Airport Hotel](https://www.istairport.com/en/passenger/airport-guide/airport-hotel) that has 174 rooms available only to airside passengers. Rooms are bookable online and can be booked for as little as 4 hours.

As the airside part of the hotel is only accessible to transit passengers you should be fine to use it without a visa.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're Indian ? If you have a schengen visa, you can get a visa on arrival at Istanbul (you have to apply online - its a simple process) and get the visa stamped against your online visa receipt. It will give you time to explore a bit of old Istanbul (the main sights are close together) and have a better choice of hotels.